# UIButton disabled state not changing with calling super method

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm using custom buttons, and I'd like to change the appearance of my button when it's disabled without images.
This is the code I'm using:

```
-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    [super setEnabled:enabled];
    if (enabled) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x961e1e);
        [[self layer] setBorderColor:[UIColorFromRGB(0x7d1919) CGColor]];
    }else{
        self.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(0x751717,0.6);
        [[self layer] setBorderColor:[UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(0x6e1616,0.6) CGColor]];
    }
}
```

If I call the `[super setEnabled:(BOOL)]` method, the appearance won't change, but if I don't call that, then the appearance changes, but the button is still clickable :/

Any idea is welcome.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "I'd like to change the appearance of my button when it's disabled without images"? Your custom UIButton has an image when enabled, and when disabled, you want the image to be hidden?

Comment: No, I'm not using images, I'm filling the background with color, then I give a border with 2px radius. If the button is disabled, I'd like to change the background and border color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating images from color, i've found a good solution for this problem here at stackoverflow.com:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageFromColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

I added this as a category to UIImage, then i set the button background images via this method with the colors i'm using.